# The stalk local nature of formal smoothness

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, smoothness

Under finite presentation hypothesis on $X/S$, I believe it should be possible to define formal smoothness using only artin local rings as the test rings. What would a reference for this fact be?

Comment: You need the finite presentation of $\Omega _{X/S}$ to conclude that $\mathcal{G}$ is quasi-coherent, see the reference to EGA I quoted in the proof.

Comment: Oh ofcourse! Thanks, that clears it up.

Comment: I am still interested in question two so let me edit the post to reflect that. After a massive edit, the above comments don't make sense but they were answering one of the two older questions I asked.

Comment: What do you mean by "it should be possible to define"? You can define whatever you want, but without noetherian assumption on $S$ formal smoothness of $X \to S$ w.r.t. to Aritin local rings and w.r.t. to all rings are different notions (even if $X \to S$ is finitely presented). It is not entirely trivial to prove that for noetherian $S$  these two notions are the same.

Comment: I am looking for a proof that they are the same with noetherian hypothesis on S (or say, finite presentation hypothesis on X/S)